# ResultSet is not updatable

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

I have read all of the "updatable" post on stackoverflow (and elsewhere on the web) but to no avail. My code was working fine then it stopped say the resultset was not updatable. This is across the 4 data files I use in the JDBC derby database. The files all have keys. I don't know where else to look. I wrote the test code below to demonstrate the problem.

```
     private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
try {
    String uName = "guest";
    String uPass = "guest";
    String host = "jdbc:derby://127.0.0.1:1527/erTracker";
    Connection erTrackerCon = DriverManager.getConnection( host,uName,uPass );
   // erTrackerCon.setAutoCommit(true);
     milestonesStmt = erTrackerCon.createStatement( ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    String SQL = "SELECT * FROM milestones order by milestoneID";
    rsMilestones = milestonesStmt.executeQuery( SQL ); 
    String a = "02";
    String b = "M";
    String c = "Move to prospect";
    erTrackerCon.setReadOnly(false);
    int concurrency = rsMilestones.getConcurrency();
    System.out.println("the answer is " + concurrency); // the answer is 1007
    rsMilestones.moveToInsertRow(); // error is: 'moveToInsertRow' not allowed because the ResultSet is not an updatable ResultSet. 
    rsMilestones.updateString("milestoneID", a);
    rsMilestones.updateString("milestoneType",b);
    rsMilestones.updateString("milestoneName", c);
    rsMilestones.insertRow( );  
   //String SQL =  "INSERT INTO milestones (milestoneid,milestonetype,milestongname) VALUES     ('02','M','move to pursue')";
   //rsMilestones = milestonesStmt.executeQuery( SQL );
}                                     
catch ( SQLException err ) {
   System.out.println( err.getMessage( ) );
   }
}
```

Comment: Slightly off topic though, why not use a stored procedure to do achieve your desired results, so that all select queries and insert/updated will be part of stored procedure in backend by passing parameters from Java to database procedure.

Comment: what is the exact exception you are getting.  Have you tried a manual update/insert using ij?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the  Derby documentation (e.g. [here](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefsqlj41360.html)) you cannot use ORDER BY in an updatable resultset.